# What is needed to get Spring Security SAML to 1.0 release

Tags: spring-security, release, saml, spring-saml

My question is the following:

What is needed bring the Spring Security SAML project to an official 1.0 release, and is there anything we can do to help?

This extremely useful framework, that I have used with great success to enable SAML-based SSO in an application, still hasn't seen an official 1.0 release. I would love to see an official GA release of it. I have read somewhere that the creator has no time to finish it off. This is a real shame. Maybe we can help finish it?

Comment: Despite my answer this question is probably off-topic for Stackoverflow, I'm available at vladimir at v7security.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm finalizing the few last [things](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/commits/master) like release package structure and documentation and plan to release 1.0.0.FINAL after the upcoming weekend.

Contribution of integration guides for Shibboleth, Ping Federate or Okta which would provide end-to-end configuration steps for enabling federation between Spring SAML and the IDP product would be great. The current [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/pdf/spring-security-saml-reference.pdf) contains one such example for ADFS.

Also all the testing and reporting of found issues to [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SES/component/10711/) is very helpful.

Comment: Btw, I confirm that ADFS-based IdPs work fine also with 1.0.0.RC2

Comment: Spring SAML 1.0.0 is now released and available in Maven Central. The official announcements will come a bit later.